# Featured post is not adding

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Problem.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to build like `Featuring Post system`. That If user click on feature this post then post should be add in featured posts.

**The Problem**

When i click on Feature this Post then it doesn't add the post in featured post page.

**What have i tried**

I also made a another model for Featuring Post BUT it didn't work so then i again implement in `Post Model`

views.py

```
def featured(request,user_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,post_owner=user_id)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post.featured.add(post)

    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'featured_posts.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    featured = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='featured',blank=True,default='')
```

urls.py

```
path('featured/<int:user_id>/',views.featured,name='featured'),
```

detail_view.html

```
{{ data.post_title }}


<a href="{% url 'mains:featured' data.id %}">Feature this Post</a>
```

featured_posts.html

```
{% for s in post.featured %}

{{ s.post_title }}

{% endfor %}
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the 404.

Comment: It is not showing `404 now`.

Answer (score -1):

You write `post.featured.add(post)` which is incorrect as `featured` is a many to many relationship between user and post. You likely want to write:

```
post.featured.add(request.user)
```

OR

```
request.user.featured.add(post)
```

Also you write `if request.method == 'POST':` yet the view is reached by a normal get request (you use an anchor tag). Remove that condition and it will work. (Best would be to change the anchor to a form with a submit button)

Also to display featured posts of a user:

```
{% for s in request.user.featured.all %}
    {{ s.post_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is still not showing post in featured page.

Comment: I think , The problem is in Models, Because i add `ManyToManyField` with `User` AND when i check it in admin then it is showing `Feature Post` and `USERS NAMES` BUT it should be the posts name. AND i think i should `ManyToManyField` with `Post`.